# Increase Aztec barcode size

Tags: zpl, aztec-barcode

I'm trying to scale an `Aztec` barcode to a `5"x5.5"` label, but the default `Aztec` encoder doesn't create any barcodes larger than about `0.25"x0.25"`.

How can I scale it larger?

My code is below:

```
^XA
^MTD
^BON,10,N,250,N,1,0
^FO100,100 ^FD Barcode Text^FS
^FO275,1350^AVN,200,200^FDText of Barcode Text^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer contradicts what the ZPL manual says.  You have the the second parameter (magnification factor) set to 10, which is the max according to the manual.   I took it up to 46 and was able to fill a 4 inch x 4 inch label. Try changing that parameter.

Comment: The 140Xi4 203 dpi printer I have didn't change the symbol size anything past 10 for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Aztec barcode command:

```
^B0a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Where `b` is the magnification. And would change the symbol's "dot" size.

Where `d` is the error control and symbol size/type indicator and would change the redundancy.

You had your `d` set to something out of the range (250), which caused it to default to 0.  More redundancy means larger symbol, but not the symbol's "dot" size.

Accepted Values for `d`:

```
0 = default error correction level
01 to 99 = error correction percentage (minimum)
101 to 104 = 1 to 4-layer compact symbol
201 to 232 = 1 to 32-layer full-range symbol
300 = a simple Aztec “Rune”
Default Value: 0
```

Example ZPL to make a "bigger" symbol:

```
^XA
^MTD
^BON,10,N,208,N,1,0
^FO100,100 ^FD Barcode Text^FS
^FO100,700^AVN,100,100^FDText of Barcode Text^FS
^XZ
```